# How to determine if there are public transit apps for your region?

Tags: google-maps, ios

In iOS 6, the built-in Maps application no longer provides public transportation information.  Instead, it kicks you to 3rd party apps that provide that functionality.  I'm currently running iOS 5, and won't update until I know there's a way to easily look up bus routes under iOS 6.  How can I determine if there are 3rd party transit apps that cover my region?

I'm being deliberately vague on the region I'm living in, as I want a generic answer that will be useful to public transit users in all regions.

Answer (score 1):

This question is outdated as Apple Maps (iOS 10) now supports transit but an alternative to Apple Maps is Google Maps which in my experience is the best way to find transit to get from A to B but I encourage you to compare both based on where you live.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: @Allan Can you share how to improve this answer? I think that a single line can be applicable in certain situations.

Comment: Two things:  It's basically an opinionated answer without supporting details.  Opinionated answer are fine, but to make it an answer that will resonate with the users you should detail *why*  "it is the best way...."  Secondly:  The OP is asking if there are specific apps for a local region.  How does your answer address the OP's question?

Comment: Much better IMO.  Vote up.  (I didn't down vote, BTW, I usually just provide feedback)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what generic answer will apply here, other than to search the App Store for a term like "`<my city name>` + transit"... Now, there are several vectors for searching the App Store: directly, through Google, or through apps and sites like [AppShopper](http://appshopper.com/) that aggregate that data.

One of those latter options might provide a specific search or list of transit apps for various regions, but I don't know of any off-hand.

That said, selecting Transit directions in the iOS 6 Maps app apparently brings up this screen ([source](http://www.macworld.com/article/2010065/review-refined-ios-6-highlighted-by-stunning-maps-overhaul.html)):

[image: Maps transit directions dialog]

Which may or may not search intelligently for applicable apps under the From the App Store section. Unfortunately, I can't test this yet - I'll do so tomorrow, after I've installed iOS 6.

Comment: It does intelligently search for applicable apps.  App makers are able to submit to Apple region data that indicates what regions their transit apps cover.  But that's of little use when you aren't going to run iOS 6 unless you know that there are suitable apps available.

Comment: Fair enough... I can't think of an answer to "how to determine if there are `<such and such` apps?" that doesn't boil down to "search for them", though. Can you perhaps clarify the question in terms of where, specifically, you want to find this information?

Comment: By "where" do you mean "where I physically live" or where as in a tool?  The question is asking for that tool.  If I edit the question to just have my specific city, then it's pretty localized.  I'm looking for a way for someone to determine if their area has a transit app.  If the only answer is 'search the app store for `region + transit`' then that's that.

Comment: I meant "where" as in a tool. And I've updated my answer based on your comments, to include the possibility of 3rd-party lists of apps.